# Displaying binded images in ListView Xamarin after selecting each from device photo library using CrossMedia

Tags: xamarin

I successfully select a picture in my PictureViewModel using the CrossMedia plugin and store it as byte[] in a Picture object. Later on I want to display this picture on a different page from that array using the following xaml code:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate >

        <DataTemplate>


            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="20">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding MyImageSource}"></Image>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding PicTitle, StringFormat='Picture Title:  {0}'}" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding PicComment, StringFormat='Comments::  {0}'}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>

                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Clicked="MenuItem_OnClicked" Text="Remove" IsDestructive="True" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see the ImageSource is binded to MyImageSource. In the viewmodel I use

```
    private ImageSource ImageSourceFromByteArray(byte[] arr)
    {
        if (arr != null && arr.Length > 0)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(arr);
            return ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);                    
        }

        return null;

    }
```

That transfers byte[] inside the object to ImageSource object that binds to XAML. The first time the picture is selected this works well. However if I go ahead and replace this selection with another picture it doesn't work. It crashes at the end of execution with a null exception even if I surround it with try and catch and doesn't return any stack trace or info on where it crashed.

I think its something to do with the stream but can't figure out what exactly. If anyone has absolutly any ideas on why this performs the way it does it would be great. I hope I was able to explain the error well enough. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the function from where you are calling the "ImageSourceFromByteArray" method?

Comment: Oh I actually managed to solve this by displaying images from file. So when I get them from the server I save them to file temporarily first and then display them from path. The stream is very unstable and bugs for no reason all the time.